# Grouping a DataFrame containing a JSON column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to de-duplicate records in a dataframe by grouping values. My data has a structure such as this:

```py
json = {
    "employees": [
        {"name": "Shyam", "email": "shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},
        {"name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com"},
        {"name": "Jai", "email": "jai87@gmail.com"},
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame({"key": ["A", "A"], "val": [1, 2], "json": [json, json]})
```

What I want to get is a single row of: `['A', [1, 2], 'json string']`

I would normally do it as follows:

```py
df.groupby(["val", "json"])["key"].apply(list)
```

Which would work fine, were it not for the json data: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. So what I do is to convert the column to string first:

```py
df["json"] = df["json"].apply(json.dumps)
df = df.groupby(["val", "json"])["key"].apply(list)
```

Then I convert the column back to JSON:

```py
df["json"] = df["json"].apply(json.loads)
```

Now, is that really the best way? I can't help but think that there must be a better one.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good and sound, but you can do it more efficiently:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

json_data = {
    "employees": [
        {"name": "Shyam", "email": "shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},
        {"name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com"},
        {"name": "Jai", "email": "jai87@gmail.com"},
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame({"key": ["A", "A"], "val": [1, 2], "json": [json_data, json_data]})

df_grouped = df.groupby("key").agg({
    "val": list,
    "json": 'first'  
}).reset_index()

print(df_grouped)
```

which is

```
 key     val                                               json
0   A  [1, 2]  {'employees': [{'name': 'Shyam', 'email': 'shy...
```

Comment: Indeed, that's much better! Thank you!